# Using from qgis.gui import * in QGIS standalone application

Tags: qgis, qgis-python-console, standalone, spyder

I have QGIS 3.28.7 installed on my computer and in its Python Console this command works:

```py
from qgis.gui import *
```

I tried to use it in some Python IDE's. For example, in Spyder.
The following paths are defined in Tools\Python Manager:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.7\apps\qgis-ltr\bin
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.7\apps\Qt5\plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.7\apps\Python39\Scripts
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.7\apps\Qt5\bin
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.7\bin
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.7\apps\qgis-ltr\python
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.7\apps\Python39
```

When I try in the Spyder panel:

```py
from qgis.gui import *
```

I receive there the following message:

```
File C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.7\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\gui\__init__.py:25
from qgis._gui import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gui: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

So what is the right way to solve the problem?